# Remove users from User Profiles after applying a LDAP Filter

Tags: search, administration, userprofiles

In our test environment i did a full AD import, forgetting to add a filter to get only a single specific department. So now i got all user instead of the one department i wanted.

What would the correct steps be to remove all the users and rerun the UPA sync? Do i only need to apply the filter and run a full sync? And reset the User profile crawl in search?

Any specific timer-jobs that need to be forced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a test environment you can run PowerShell to delete the User Profiles that you don't need.

```
$context = Get-SPServiceContext -Site http://mysite
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
#Create a filter if necessary, this will just list them
$upm.GetEnumerator() | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq 'john'} | ft DisplayName
#Finally you can use this to remove the profile
$upm.RemoveProfile($profile)
```

Note: This is NOT a script to run. I did that intentionally since it would be way too easy for someone to erase all their profiles and then blame me. Some assembly is required.